# How can I correct "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime" without editing function signature?

Tags: rust

Background: I'm creating an iterator that returns a reference to a slice `&[T]`, but the data vector needs to remain immutable. The iterator **cannot** modify the original data, but must return the same slice pointer repeatedly after it has modified it. I've considered having my iterator own a `Vec<T>`, but I would like to avoid that (and it didn't seem to work). I avoid allocations since I plan to use it mostly in realtime audio and allocations could potentially block. Code:

```
pub struct Windower<'a, 'b, T: 'a + 'b> {
    window_type: WindowType,
    hop_size: usize,
    bin_size: usize,
    current_index: usize,
    data: &'a [T],
    out_data: &'b mut [T]
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Float + FromPrimitive> Iterator for Windower<'a, 'b, T> {
    type Item = &'b [T];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.current_index < (self.len() - 1) {
            let start = self.current_index * self.hop_size;
            let end = start + self.bin_size;
            self.current_index += 1;
            let window = self.window();
            let data_iter = self.data[start..end].iter();

            for &mut v in self.out_data {
                let val: T = window.next().unwrap() * 
                     *data_iter.next().unwrap();
                v = val;
            }

            Some(self.out_data)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Returns the error:

```
src/waves.rs:160:18: 160:31 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/waves.rs:160             Some(self.out_data)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/waves.rs:146:5: 164:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn next(&'b mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this. I can't make the change suggested, because the trait implementation for Iterator does not have an explicit lifetime parameter.

Comment: It would help if you posted a self-contained example that compiles except for your problem. You probably need to either return a reference or require `Copy` for `T`, but I can't easily test that.

Comment: I think you want something similar to what I coded in [sliding_windows](https://github.com/flo-l/rust-sliding_windows/). Check out [this](https://github.com/flo-l/rust-sliding_windows/blob/master/src/sliding_windows.rs#L103) for example. My Iterator returns a custom struct Window which dereferences to a slice, see [here](https://github.com/flo-l/rust-sliding_windows/blob/master/src/sliding_windows.rs#L123). ([Iterator impl](https://github.com/flo-l/rust-sliding_windows/blob/master/src/sliding_windows.rs#L174))

Comment: The deeper problem here is: Rusts Iterator trait is defined so that the values returned by next() can outlive the Iterator itself. This is reflected in the [signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next): `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>`. No lifetimes. But you're trying to return a slice, which needs a lifetime. You'd need `fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a Self::Item>` (or something similar...this is called a streaming Iterator, it's not part of rust's stdlib yet).

Comment: the solution I chose in sliding_sindows is decoupling storage and Iterator, so that the lifetime of the window is bound to the lifetime of the storage and not the adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

Rust prevents you from having more than one alias to an object if one of them is a mutable alias.

Here, `Windower::out_data` is a mutable alias to some slice, and you're trying to return an immutable alias to the same data from your `next` method. In order for this to be safe, Rust must prevent you from being able to use `Windower::out_data` for as long as the slice returned by `next` is in scope. This means that the signature `fn next(&'b mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>` is indeed required, which means you simply cannot implement `Iterator` with your current implementation.

Comment: I see. I'm modeling my functionality after IterMut, however, which does something similar. But I suppose that if the stdlib authors had to use `unsafe`, then I probably do as well.